# C++-CLI how do I convert String^ (from a textbox) to something that a function which takes void* type variables, will accept?

Tags: c++-cli

I have the following function from a dll:

```
aisgdll_setinfo(int dev, set_field_code field, void *data);
```

I know how to deal with the first two parameters. I have a textbox the user enters data into and the textbox returns a variable of type String^. I somehow need to get the data from that textbox and do something, so that I can write it to this function to the void *data parameter.

Comment: There's nowhere near enough information here to solve your problem.  What character encoding that that function require?  How long will it hold the pointer?  Does it read from the buffer, or write to it, or both?

Comment: The function will load the data into a buffer. Other than this, I cannot answer the other questions. I do not have a lot of experience with this kind of coding.

Comment: You will need to read up on what that API call expects. Once you know that, indicate in your question and then someone here might be able to help.

Comment: It seems like the expected use of the data parameter would depend on the value of the code parameter. Perhaps that will help you find some documentation. Tip: once you do, write a wrapper function around this one to help document that in code. This function signature is too abstract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research online, I have found some solutions to the problems I was having. The functions I was plugging the retrieved values into needed pointers. I think these solutions can be adapted by others for their own purposes. For converting the Visual Studio Text box String^ to char*:

```
char* iData = (char*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(activeBox->Text).ToPointer();
```

When I needed to get a floating point number from a Text box, I used the following:

```
int anInteger = (int)((Convert::ToDouble(activeBox->Text))*10);
int *iData = &anInteger;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this form.
I used the Thread :: Sleep to prevent abuse in processing. While your thread does not change the status of the screen will be updated.

```
void solve()
{
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Threading;
Thread^ bot_thread = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(bot_run));
bot_thread->Start(); 

PictureBox^ PB_LoadGIF = gcnew PictureBox();
PB_LoadGIF->Visible = true;
while (bot_thread->ThreadState == ThreadState::Running)
{
    Thread::Sleep(1000);
    PB_LoadGIF->Parent->Refresh();
}
```

}